# Program error on source insight using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wine, source-insight

I was using Source Insight 3.5 on Ubuntu 10.10 32bit. For some reason, while I was working, the program got stuck. I closed it, and ever since, when I try to open it, I get the following error message:

> Program Error
>
> The program Insight3.exe has encountered a serious problem and needs
>   to close. We are sorry for the inconvenience.

Restarting the computer didn't help. Uninstalling the program and wine and then reinstalling them didn't help as well. I still get the same error message.

Anyone to the rescue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu go to ~/Source Insight/ and remove project directory content and setting directory
content and then open source insight and load your existing .PR file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. So to resolve it you have to blow away the GLOBAL.CF3 file each time before you launch Source Insight inside of WINE.

Then, to backup your settings, you can do a Save Settings AS and call it something other than GLOBAL.CF3. Then, after you delete GLOBAL.CF3 and launch Source Insight, I go to Options > Load Configuration and load my backup.CF3 file. When you close out of Source Insight it will recreate the GLOBAL.CF3 file which you'll, again, have to delete the next time you go to launch Source Insight.

Eventually, I stopped working this way and now use Source Insight on a Windows PC and work on my source code on the Linux PC over a samba share.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem as well, blew away the configuration, updated Source Insight to later sub-version (.66 or .72) and restarted it. Didn't have the issue again.